# How to convert json from one to another and set some defaults in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following input :

```json
{
  "error-response": [
    {
      "code": 1401,
      "status": "No TITLE Found in request"
    },
    {
      "code": 1402,
      "status": "No FIRST_NAME Found in request"
    },
    {
      "code": 1403,
      "status": "No LAST_NAME Found in request"
    },
    {
      "code": 1404,
      "status": "No EMAIL ID Found in request"
    }
  ]
}
```

I will like to do the following in my jolt spec

1. check that the json is has a node "error-response"
2. check all the objects in the array, if there is a code 1401 , output "status" of "REJECT" and associated detail of "No TITLE Found in request"
3. If there is no 1401 in the list, then set "status" to ERROR and set the "status_detail" a string containing the comma separated values of the statuses
   6.Then, I would like to add some additional name-value nodes which are nulls.

The output I want is the following:

```json
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "status_detail": "No TITLE Found in request,No FIRST_NAME Found in request,No LAST_NAME Found in request,No EMAIL ID Found in request",
  "monthly_repayment": null,
  "accept_token": null,
  "total_charge": null,
  "offered": null,
  "product_type": "Unsecured",
  "approval_probability": null,
  "first_repayment": null,
  "lender_branch": null,
  "total": null,
  "phone": null
}
```

Comment: Hi Mega, the input seems not to comply with the expected output based on those five condition. As an example, you have four different objects with different `code` values within the array in the input, but want to get only one `status` attribute ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I need to check the code attribute, if it 1401, I will output a status of REJECT and a status details of "No TITLE Found in request". But, if the code is not 1401, I want to set that matching status but with a status details containing all the other details.

Comment: Hello Barbaros and others, I have made some progress and have a much simpler issue. Which I will raise another question for.